# Spurious semicolon

Tags: bug, status-completed

The input of my comment to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402194/18401) is just:

> When you say "However, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329209/4427", do you just mean "`thmmarks` is evil!" or am I missing something?

But the output is (note the spurious semicolon):

> When you say "However, see also tex.stackexchange.com/a/329209/4427";, do you just mean "thmmarks is evil!" or am I missing something?

Comment: When you say "However, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329209/4427", do you just mean "thmmarks is evil!" or am I missing something? (test -- yes, here too!)

Comment: Related: [Escaping an end-of-link parenthesis with a backslash causes a complimentary semicolon to appear out of thin air](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161666/168244)

Comment: @Werner Thanks to your link, I found out maybe even more related: [strange character replacement on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83837/371635) whose [first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83855/371635) explains what I observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed as described on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83857/235711).

For most cases it will produce the correct URL. For all cases it won't add a semicolon.